# Acessing iphone with python

Tags: python, ios, iphone

I was wondering if there is a tool out there, which I can use to control my iPhone with python, e.g. take screenshots and process them with my laptop and mimic touchscreen input and so on. 
While searching for it, I found several tools which accomplish this task, but only work on an Android (e.g. using adb shell).

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks